# States: KMS-Condition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with dynamics $\tau$.

Consider a state $\omega$.

> Does it suffice to have on a dense set the KMS-condition:
>   $$F(t+i\beta)=\lim_nF_n(t+i\beta)=\omega(\tau^t[B_n]A_n)=\omega(\tau^t[B]A)$$
>   *(I wonder wether it may fail to be analytic; is this important?)*

*(Usually, one can check this for the dense set of entire elements.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it does not suffice!**

It can even severely fail to extend to the complex plane at all.

*(See the thread: [Analyticity: Uniform Limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113969/79762))*