# Analyticity: Uniform Limit

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

**Problem**

Consider a uniformly bounded sequence over the real line:
$$f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad|f_n(x)|\leq L$$

Suppose they have analytic continuations with common domain:
$$F_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:\quad F_n\restriction_\mathbb{R}=f_n$$

> Does their uniform limit have an analytic continuation, too?
>   $$F:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:\quad F\restriction_\mathbb{R}=f\quad(f_n\stackrel{\infty}{\to}f)$$
>   *(By uniform boundedness this seems very likely; but really?)*

**Application**

An almost modular state is modular:
$$A\in\mathcal{A}^\omega:\quad\omega(\sigma^t[A]B)=\omega(B\sigma^{t+i\beta}[A])\quad(B\in\mathcal{A})$$
*(Supposed that entire elements are dense.)*

Comment: If you assume, in addition, that $F_n$ is locally uniformly bounded, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @sranthrop: Not sure about that; I mean on the real axis yes but the extensions, hmm.

Comment: @sranthrop: In fact, I do have even that the sequence is uniformly bounded: $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)|<\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I found an applied counterexample...*

Consider a Hamiltonian dynamics:
$$H:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad U(t)\varphi:=e^{-itH}\varphi$$

Regard the entire elements:
$$\mathcal{C}^\omega:=\{\varphi:e^{-itH}\varphi=\sum\frac{1}{k!}(it)^kH^k\varphi\}$$

Then even the entire elements are dense:
$$\overline{\mathcal{C}^\omega}=\mathcal{H}:\quad U(t)\varphi_n\to U(t)\varphi\in\mathcal{H}$$

But still it has elements that are not analytic at all:
$$\mathcal{D}\subsetneq\mathcal{H}:\quad U(z)\varphi_n\nrightarrow U(z)\varphi\notin\mathcal{H}$$

*(The weak version boils down to numerical functions.)*

Answer (score 1):

No, this is in general not true. Let $D = (-1,1)^2$, let $\Omega=\mathbb{R} \times (-1,1)$, both viewed as subsets of the complex plane, and let $\phi:D \to \Omega$ be the conformal map with $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi'(0)>0$, so that $\phi((-1,1)) = \mathbb{R}$. Using this conformal map, we can translate your problem into a similar problem on $D$, as follows: If we have analytic functions $f_n:D \to \mathbb{C}$, with $f_n \to f$ on $(-1,1)$ uniformly convergent to a bounded limit $f$, does $f$ necessarily have an analytic continuation to $D$? However, by Runge's theorem any function $f$ which is analytic in some neighborhood of $[-1,1]$ is a uniform limit of (complex analytic) polynomials on $[-1,1]$. Now just pick $f$ to have a singularity somewhere in $D$, and let $(f_n)$ be the sequence of polynomials given by Runge's theorem, and you will get a contradiction to your statement.

Comment: Can you explain conformal map verbally, please?

Comment: It is an analytic diffeomorphism. The fact that it exists in this case is the Riemann mapping theorem. By modifying $D$ you can easily modify it to have an explicitly given conformal map (which I probably should have done, but I was too lazy...)

Comment: Don't you mean Stone-Weierstraß instead of Runge's theorem? *(Runge's theorem only guarantees approximation by rational functions while Stone-Weierstraß approves approximation by polynomial functions.)*

Comment: In any case, nice answer: That unveils the problem. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: Runge's theorem gives approximation by polynomials in the special case where the compact set does not disconnect the plane. In general you can approximate by rational functions which have exactly one pole in each complementary component. Stone-Weierstrass does not directly apply in this situation, as far as I know.